# List.Js não funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um web app usando EMBER e quero usar em um determinado lugar o **[ListJS](http://www.listjs.com/)** para listar discussões mas não esta funcionando. segue o codigo:

```
   function(List){
        var options = {
          listClass: 'list',
          valueNames: [ 'discussion' ]
          };

          var discussionList = new List('matheus', options);
            });
      });

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="discussions">
    <div class="large-4 columns forum-discussions" id="matheus">
        <!-- Menu de funcionalidades -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="larger-2 columns text-center">
                <!-- Search -->
                <a href="#" class="button round option" id="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>

                <!-- New discussion -->
                {{#link-to 'discussions.new' classNames="button round option"}}
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                {{/link-to}}
            </div>

            <!-- toggle effect begin-->

            <!--search-->
            <div class="forum-search forum-events">
                <input type="text" class="search"  value="" placeholder="Buscar Discussão">
            </div>

            <!-- end of toggle effect-->

            <hr class="forum-divisor">
        </div>
        <!-- Listagem de discussões -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 forum-discussions-list">
                <ul class="list">
                    {{#each discussion in model}}
                        {{#link-to 'discussion' discussion}}
                        <li>
                            <div class="larger-4 forum-photo">
                            <!--photo-->
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p class="discussion">{{discussion.title}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        {{/link-to}}

                        <hr class="forum-divisor">
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
    </script>
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Parte do começo do javascript está faltando. Complete o snippet para nos ajudar a lhe ajudar.